# Java: For Loop stops after one element in a recursive function

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, tree

I am building a tree structure in java from scratch. For getting the height of my tree I am using a recursive function.

Each note (IP) contains a list of all connections it has, including there parent.  My idea was to loop over all children and call the height function again when it's not the parent.

My problem is, that it only calls one child and does not loop over all possible children. Maybe someone can tell me where is my fault.

If one Note has two children and each of them also has another two. It only views the first one at both iterations.

```
 public int recursiveGetHight(final Node node, Node parent) {
    Node viewPoint = getViewPoint(node);
    int h = 0;
    for (Node child : viewPoint.getChildren()) {
        if (child.getChildren().size() <= 1) {
            return 0;
        } else if(parent == null || child.getValue() != parent.getValue()){
            h = recursiveGetHight(child, viewPoint) + 1;
            return h;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Exempel:

```
root
    - note 1
        - sub note 1
        - sub note 2
            - x
            - y
    - note 2
        - sub note 1
         - z
        - sub note 2

int h = recurisvHeight(root, null)

result should be 3 but the function returns 2.
```

If I at a print command inside the for loop

```
System.out.println(child);
```

it shows:
note1
sub note 1

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and explain a bit more, what your expected result should be. From what I see in your example, you are returning a value (return 0; / return h;) and will therefore not loop through all childrens but just the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use return, when you make a return your function end.
You have to remove the first return = 0 and make an ArrayList of child and replace return h in the by loop by append the child in the list.